# How to get actionView in Android BottomNavigation View

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom layout that I want to put in the BottomNavigationView menu. Just like the NavigationView I want to set the custom layout in the NavigationView Drawer, but no matter how I tried I still cannot get the custom layout display in the bottom view.

Steps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                          android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh"
                                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                          android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary_color"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header_logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!-- Main container for fragment or other views -->
        <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_home_bottom"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And the menu XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_overview"
        android:title=""
        app:actionLayout="@layout/bottomview_icon_menu"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView|"
    />
</menu>
```

The custom view looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
              android:background="@color/alpha_color"
              android:layout_width="50dp"
              android:layout_height="56dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray_color"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_subheading_size"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hihi"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_subheading_size"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My call method in OnCreate() is like this:

```
mBottomView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_view);
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_overview);
View view = item.getActionView();
```

In here, view always get null.

The problem is no matter how I did, the button view shows only a blank on the screen, and I always cannot get action layout from the menu object.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

`BottomNavigationView` does not support `ActionView`s.

`BottomNavigationView` uses a number of [internal classes (everything started with `BottomNavigation`)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/). Looking at the [`BottomNavigationMenuView`'s `buildMenuView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/BottomNavigationMenuView.java#251), it does not take into account any `ActionView` set on the `MenuItem`.

Comment: I think this is the answer since I used break point to check the menu object but I couldn't found any related view. It's really confusing because the methods are existing but actually not support.

Comment: @TaoBit - `<menu>` is a generic way of defining a menu: it doesn't mean that every implementation that uses a menu supports every part of the API.

Comment: Links are broken, please check